# CollectionView multiple filter

Tags: c#, wpf, filter

I want to do something like Google does in its search: if the user write some special char, like - or * the results are filtered.

What I have now: a filter that filters objects `Name` property with `Contains` method, and two special characters:

- for leaving only the names that don't contain the typed text -
- for searching a different property of my object (in my case it is `Units`) *

Ok, what I need is to combine above logic and be able to first filter with "-" or "*" and then be able to type and continue filtering the remaining results.

It's all about the logic I think, but it's getting complicated and I might need a little help.

```
item.View.Filter = delegate(object o)
            {
                //Lógica de filtrado

                if ((item.FilterText.Length > 0) && ((item.FilterText[0] == '*') || (item.FilterText[0] == '-')))
                {
                    //If the first char is *
                    if ((item.FilterText[0] == '*')
                        && (((MyObject)o).Units[0].ToString().ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
.Contains(item.FilterText.ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Substring(1))
                            || ((MyObject)o).Units[1].ToString().ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
.Contains(item.FilterText.ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Substring(1))))


                {
                        return true;
                    }

                    //If the first char is -
                    if ((item.FilterText[0] == '-')
                        && (!((MyObject)o).Name.ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
.Contains(item.FilterText.ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Substring(1))
                            || !((MyObject)o).Name.ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
.Contains(item.FilterText.ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Substring(1))))


                 {
                        return true;
                 }

                }
                else
                {
                    if (((MyObject)o).Name.ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
.Contains(item.FilterText.ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                };
```

Comment: Use RegularExpressions to break down strings.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the '...I might need a little help...' part of the question?  Are you asking how to implement a dictionary of chained predicate methods?

Comment: Finally I've achieved what I needed splitting the input text in words and then apply a set of rules for each word, if all conditions are satisfied the object remains in the view. For example, now I'm able to write something like: bob -mary -rob *london.